# Creating logical arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab

I've been learning matlab for the past week as my job requires it, but I'm kinda stuck. I want to create a function that removes all data points within lowerBound and upperBound. What's wrong with this code?

```
mask = ~((data.HB_X > lowerBound) && (data.HB_X < upperBound));
data.HB_X = data.HB_X(mask);
data.HB_Y = data.HB_Y(mask);
```

The error is

```
??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in ==> myGUI>deleteHBs at 228
        mask = ~((data.HB_X > lowerBound) && (data.HB_X < upperBound));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message says. You can only use the shortcut operators `&&` and `||` for scalar comparisons. If you compare arrays, you need to use `&` and `|`, respectively.

Comment: @Hannesh: Don't worry. This feeling will help you remember better :)